# for loop vectorization optimization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I need to add a column `month` to the dataframe. When the `start date` and `end date` of a row of `data` contain the first day of certain months, then add these months to the `month` column. I can only use the most primitive for loop to process. My data is about 300 rows. How can I optimize it if I use vectorization?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "d_month": ['202109', '202109', '202109', '202106', '202106', '202106', '202105', '202105', '202105', '202104',
                    '202104', '202104', '202103', '202103', '202103', ],
        "code": ['A202109', 'B202109', 'C202109', 'A202106', 'B202106', 'C202106', 'A202105', 'B202105', 'C202105',
                 'A202104', 'B202104', 'C202104', 'A202103', 'B202103', 'C202103'],
        "start_date": ['20210118', '20210118', '20210118', '20201019', '20201019', '20201019', '20210322', '20210322',
                       '20210322', '20210222', '20210222', '20210222', '20200720', '20200720', '20200720'],
        "end_date": ['20210917', '20210917', '20210917', '20210618', '20210618', '20210618', '20210521', '20210521',
                     '20210521', '20210416', '20210416', '20210416', '20210319', '20210319', '20210319'], })
data = data.sort_values(by=['d_month', 'code'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
result = pd.DataFrame()
s = data['d_month'].sort_values(ascending=True).drop_duplicates()
for i in s.values:
    d1 = str(i) + '01'
    v1 = data[(data.start_date <= d1) & (data.end_date >= d1)].reset_index(drop=True)
    v1['month'] = i
    result = pd.concat([result, v1])

result = result.sort_values(by=['month', 'd_month', 'code'], ascending=[True, True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
result = result[['month', 'd_month', 'code', 'start_date', 'end_date']]
print('Original data:')
print(data.head(10))
print('Expected data:')
print(result.head(10))
```

Output result:

```
Original data:
  d_month     code start_date  end_date
0  202103  A202103   20200720  20210319
1  202103  B202103   20200720  20210319
2  202103  C202103   20200720  20210319
3  202104  A202104   20210222  20210416
4  202104  B202104   20210222  20210416
5  202104  C202104   20210222  20210416
6  202105  A202105   20210322  20210521
7  202105  B202105   20210322  20210521
8  202105  C202105   20210322  20210521
9  202106  A202106   20201019  20210618
Expected data:
    month d_month     code start_date  end_date
0  202103  202103  A202103   20200720  20210319
1  202103  202103  B202103   20200720  20210319
2  202103  202103  C202103   20200720  20210319
3  202103  202104  A202104   20210222  20210416
4  202103  202104  B202104   20210222  20210416
5  202103  202104  C202104   20210222  20210416
6  202103  202106  A202106   20201019  20210618
7  202103  202106  B202106   20201019  20210618
8  202103  202106  C202106   20201019  20210618
9  202103  202109  A202109   20210118  20210917
```

Comment: what are these certain months? From what I understand you're only going to get one value

Comment: A code may span several months. I need to calculate the spanned months. Therefore, one line of raw data will become many lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is get all unique months and pass to `merge` for cross join with helper column `a` for all combinations and then filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last sorting and change order of columns if necessary:

```
df = data.assign(a=1)
df1 = df[['a','d_month']].drop_duplicates().rename(columns={'d_month':'month'})
df = df.merge(df1, on='a')
df = df[(df.start_date <= df['month']) & (df.end_date >= df['month'])].drop('a', axis=1)

df = df.sort_values(by=['month', 'd_month', 'code'], ignore_index=True)
df = df[df.columns[-1:].tolist() + df.columns[:-1].tolist()]

print (df.head(10))
    month d_month     code start_date  end_date
0  202103  202103  A202103   20200720  20210319
1  202103  202103  B202103   20200720  20210319
2  202103  202103  C202103   20200720  20210319
3  202103  202104  A202104   20210222  20210416
4  202103  202104  B202104   20210222  20210416
5  202103  202104  C202104   20210222  20210416
6  202103  202106  A202106   20201019  20210618
7  202103  202106  B202106   20201019  20210618
8  202103  202106  C202106   20201019  20210618
9  202103  202109  A202109   20210118  20210917
```